# ¿Como convertir una IP a byte?

Tags: java

Tengo este  código:

```
byte bEnviar[] = "jose" .getBytes();

byte ip[] = { 200,0,0,1 };

InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
```

El problema es que me da un error de

> Posible pérdida al convertir de int a byte[]

Y el ejemplo que estoy viendo para realizar mi socket lo tiene así

¿Qué paso debo realizar para usarlo en modo de Bytes?

Comment: Puedes probar la clase de GK Spencer, publicada en Java2s: [Convert a TCP/IP address string into a byte array](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/ConvertaTCPIPaddressstringintoabytearray.htm) Ejemplo: `IPAddress.parseNumericAddress("10.0.0.1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que no deberías transformar un entero a byte porque tal y como te advierte, generaría perdida de precisión. Deberías usar cada número como un byte. Aquí te paso un ejemplo:

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.1");
byte[] bytes = ip.getAddress();

//Ejemplo de impresión de la IP
for (byte b : bytes) {
    System.out.println(b & 0xFF);
}
```